# How do i chain statements together in a block with HJavaScript

Tags: haskell

```
Sequence (toBlock $ VarDeclAssign "foo" (JBool False)) (Return $ JBool True)
```

This is the only way I can do it at the moment. I tried a `foldl` but `EmptyBlock` has a different type so it wouldn't build.

Can I use do notation or something here instead?

Comment: Is this Language.HJavaScript?  http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HJavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [the documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HJavaScript/0.4.7/doc/html/Language-HJavaScript-Syntax.html#t%3aBlock), the problem is that the types of `EmptyBlock` and `Sequence` are

```
EmptyBlock :: Block ()   
Sequence :: Block () -> Stmt t -> Block t
```

Most statements are of type `Stmt ()`, except for `Return :: Expr t -> Stmt t`. From what I can tell, this is to ensure that there can only be a single return statement in a block, and it must be at the end.

The reason why `foldl Sequence EmptyBlock` didn't work for you is that `foldl` has the type `(a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a`, and if you look at the first argument, it's clear that `Sequence` can only be used if you pick `t = ()` so that `a = Block ()` and `b = Stmt ()`.

This means that you can use `foldl` to combine all statements *except* for the `Return`, which you have to manually insert at the end. Hopefully, that shouldn't be too inconvenient.